# AutoSuggestBox FontFamily Consolas not taking

Tags: xaml, uwp

Not able to get AutoSuggestBox to accept Consolas or Courier New. Suggestions?

```
<AutoSuggestBox Text="Not Taking Consolas" Width="250" Height="40" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="18" />
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with Template10

Answer (score 2):

AutoSuggestBox's template is composed of an inner TextBox and a ListView for the suggestions. The default AutoSuggestBox style sets its own values for the TextBox's FontFamily (and other properties), thus it does not inherit the value from the AutoSuggestBox. AutoSuggestBox does, however, expose a property TextBoxStyle which you can change to affect the appearance of the TextBox. You might also want to change the ItemContainerStyle too if you want the FontFamily to be applied to the ListView as well.

```
<AutoSuggestBox>
    <AutoSuggestBox.TextBoxStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        </Style>
    </AutoSuggestBox.TextBoxStyle>
    <AutoSuggestBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        </Style>
    </AutoSuggestBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```